# Why is my texture drawn in a different place when in fullscreen?

Tags: libgdx, textures, rendering

I'm trying to draw a texture (with a crescent moon) in the middle of the y-axis:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(lune, 0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
}
```

It renders this when windowed:

[image: windowed render]

And in full screen mode:

[image: full screen render]

I don't understand why it doesn't work since I'm always drawing at the top of the middle in the y-axis.

---

I add a little update to what i do exactly :

```
        @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
            this.levelDatas.screenWidth = width;
            this.levelDatas.screenHeight = height;
            this.levelDatas.lune.updateSize(width, height);
    }
```

My render method :

```
        @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            this.levelDatas.batch.begin();
            this.background.draw(this.levelDatas.batch);
            this.levelDatas.lune.draw(this.levelDatas.batch);
            this.levelDatas.batch.end();
            [...]
```

And this is the updateSize and draw method for the "Lune" object :

```
public void updateSize(int width, int height) {
    this.widthScreen = width;
    this.heightScreen = height;
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(new TextureRegion(lune), 0, this.heightScreen / 2, 0, 0, this.lune.getWidth(), this.lune.getHeight(), 1f, 1f, 0);
}
```

Still got the problem !

Comment: Can you also specify the version of LibGDX that you use?

Comment: I use the 0.9.9 version, i saw that they updated it today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the answer and it was pretty stupid. I don't understand how this work but let's admit that. Game is loaded in 1200x720. I keep this values inside of the Lune classes. And everytime i draw the Lune, i draw it at 720/2 and the scale does the work to place it at the correct place. Less talk, more code, here is my solution to my own problem : 
This is the constructor :

```
this.widthScreen = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
this.heightScreen = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

And this is the render method :

```
batch.draw(new TextureRegion(lune), 0, (this.heightScreen / 2) - (this.lune.getHeight() / 2), 0, 0, this.lune.getWidth(), this.lune.getHeight(), 1f, 1f, 0);
```

I don't understand why, but the moon is placed correctly, see :
Original size : 
[image: windowed render]

Full screen :
[image: fullscreen render]

Lowered : 
[image: lower render]

If anyone have any explanation, i'm here to listen !

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is , that

```
Gdx.graphics.getHeight()
```

doesn't get updated properly. (I tested this behavior and found out, that it's getting updated properly . I am sorry for this wrong information of mine.)

My solution:

create 2 variables

```
private int w,h;
```

Get the height and width of the window:

```
public void create() {
        w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
}
```

And then update the to every time, the resolution gets changed:

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    w = width;
    h = height;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` returns the wrong value, it's a bug. Do the developers know?

Comment: I think , that it returns the wrong value only on resize, at least i think it is like that. ( Do you use java 1.7 ? This may causes some problems)

Comment: Can you confirm with testing? I've a few projects that would have broke if this was the case.

Comment: Okay, i tested it and everything was just fine and I think I was wrong. I posted this because i had this strange behavior once.

Comment: @Klitz That's important detail that you should add to the answer!

Comment: Well it changes nothing for me. My texture is still going top when my windows is larger and going bottom when it's getting smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for SpriteBatch, it looks like vertices are generated like this:

```
final float fx2 = x + width;
final float fy2 = y + height;
```

This means even if you render at the "center" of the screen along the y-axis, it most likely will not do that. Had the SpriteBatch had something like:

```
final float fy2 = (y - height/2) + height;
```

I suspect it would be correct?

Imagine a screen height of 100, and a texture height of 50. The middle of the screen would be 50. So if you rendered the texture at 50, what would happen in the SpriteBatch is that y = 50, and fy2 = 100. That's not the middle of the screen. However, if you put y as 50 - (50/2) = 25, fy2 would be 75, and it should render in the middle.

So, (big disclaimer!!) unless libgdx does some translation somewhere else that I dont know about (and that's quite possible, since I don't know libgdx at all),

try:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(lune, 0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - (lune.getHeight()/2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this in your resize method and see if it works. It worked for me, but sincerely speaking, I don't know why.

```
batch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, width, height);
```